# Use pread() in C

Tags: c, unistd.h

I was trying to read a file using pread(), but I got "Implicit declaration of function 'pread' is invalid in C99". Is there any way to handle this?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
        char dst[20];
        int file = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
        int read_res = pread(file, dst, 10, 3);
        close(file);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: When you get an error you don't understand the very first thing to do is just to paste the entire error into a search engine and hit enter.

Comment: If you read e.g. [the Linux manual page for `pread`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) and check the "Feature Test Macro Requirements", do your code fulfill them?

Comment: Are you using `-std=c99`?  Don't do that. Use `-std=gnu99` instead.